show that all states are recurrent in a markov chain
Define $\tau_x = \inf\{n > 0: X_n = x\}$.
Suppose that show that $(P^n)_{xy} > 0$ for all $x,y \in S$ and for some $z \in S$  we have $P_z(\tau_z < \infty) = 1$. Then  show that for all $x \in S$ we have $P_x(\tau_x < \infty) = 1$.
I was able to show $P_x(\tau_z < \infty) = 1$ for all $x \in S$, but i think i still need to show $P_z(\tau_x < \infty)$ for all $x\in S$ .
Im completely stuck any suggestions?
